# Getting object data from API and then displaying it (React Fetch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to extract the data from this API https://fe-assignment.vaimo.net/ to render the object name. It should be a drone sale item but I cant display it on mapping or such.

I only have to extract this items data and there are no other objects or such in the API. I want to eventually display the product with its image, and all its attributes but I am just trying to extract simple strings from the JSON like the product name.

The result of the above code when ran is simply the heading with no further content. Both console logs return the API data in full. See ComponentDidMount and render

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Colors from "./components/Colors"
import DetailsThumb from "./components/DetailsThumb"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://fe-assignment.vaimo.net/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(data => { console.log(data)
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: data,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let content = null
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading..</div>;
    } else {
      console.log(items)
      if (items.data){
        content = items.map((product, key) => <div>{product.name}</div>)
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>The drone page</h1>
          {content}
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you share the structure of `items`, please? At `if (items.data){` it seems that `items` is an object with a prop `data`. However, at the very next line the code reads: `content = items.map(`. This leads one to think that `items` is an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting a list of products, you are getting a single product, so instead of this:

```
if (items.data){
   content = items.map((product, key) => <div>{product.name}</div>)
}
```

You should do this:

```
if (items) {
  content = <div>{items.product.name}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works now. That items.data was not calling. Its displaying

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your issue. Thank you!

Comment: You can do it by clicking on the tick mark next to the 2 arrows on the left of my answer! Thx

Comment: The JSON contains headings like 4k and 1080p with more data under those. But When I try items.product.1080p.value, react throws up an error. 

How does one get data from under headings like that containing numeric characters?

Comment: The structure is different: it is items.product.options.1080p

Comment: items.product.options.1080p throws a parsing error. 
"Identifier directly after number"

Comment: ok, then items.product.options["1080p"] should do the trick! If it leads to a bigger issue, you should consider to post a new question ;)

Comment: Thats the one, Thanks Tisiboth

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing the result of map function (an array) in a new array.

```
if (items.data){
    content = items.map((product, key) => <div>{product.name}</div>)
  }
```

You should do this

```
if (items.data){
    content = items.product.name
  }
```